# jQuery ajax: Request a page that contains JS

Tags: jquery

I need to apply AJAX loader that loads some different contents form the page, to a existing CMS.
The problem is that some of those contents, contain included JS Files or inHTML JS.

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: refURL,
success: function(resultData){
//returns the content in $content
   showContents($(resultData), title);
},
error: function(){
  showContents("something went wrong", "ERROR 404");
}
});
```

showContents() uses .HTML() to place the content into $(resultData) after some fancy animation. This works fine as long as there is no JS in the requested pages..

Is there any way i could make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should use directly the `innerHTML` property of the element you are using.

```
$('selector_for_element_to_hold_results')[0].innerHTML = resultData;
```

and pass it to the `showContents` method in raw format `showContents(resultData, title);`

(*if the resultData is what you want to insert in the DOM*)

Comment: resultData is what i insert into the DOM. this worked perfectly. Thank you!